# Error "c# referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto"

Tags: c#, windows-forms, windows

en mi aplicación Windows forms, tengo una lista de strings guardada en User Settings, la cual se llama FileList.
El problema es que me aparece un error, el código es el siguiente:

```
private void HomeForm_Load_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AlarmPicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        AlarmPicker.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss";
        if (Settings.Default.Counter > 0)
        {
            ErrorNoFilesLabel.Visible = false;
        }
        HomeDarkTheme();
        BackWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
private void      backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Settings.Default.FileList.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string TheFile in Settings.Default.FileList)
            {
                int I = 8;
                BackWorker.ReportProgress(I);
            }
        }
    }
private void BackWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if  (Settings.Default.FileList.Count > 0)
        {


            foreach (string TheFile in Settings.Default.FileList)
            {
                Reminders.TaskUC Task = new Reminders.TaskUC();
                Point TP = new Point();
                Task.Name = "Task" + Settings.Default.Counter.ToString();
                TP.Y = 1;
                int Add = 300;
                int Result = Start;
                int Distance = 100;
                Control Last = Controls[Controls.Count - 1];
                TP.X = Last.Location.X + Distance;
                if (Settings.Default.Counter == 1)
                {
                    TP.X = 300;
                }
                Size PanelWidth = new Size();
                PanelWidth.Width = ReminderPanel.Width + 300;
                PanelWidth.Height = ReminderPanel.Height;
                Task.Location = TP;
                this.Controls.Add(Task);
                ReminderPanel.Size = PanelWidth;
                ReminderPanel.Controls.Add(Task);
                XmlSerializer XS = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Information>));
                StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(TheFile);
                Information i;
            }
        }
    }
```

El problema antes se mostraba en la línea:

```
foreach (string TheFile in Settings.Default.FileList)
```

Pero ahora agregué la línea:

```
if (Settings.Default.FileList.Count > 0)
```

Y Ahora muestra el error ahí

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20140076/939213

```
Settings.Default.FileList = new List<string>();
```

[“c# referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto” => Google Translate => "C # reference to object not established as instance of an object" => Google Search => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140047/how-to-solve-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object ]